Adding empty line based on cell value and i loop which crash
I have a code as below. First part is to add one empty line (this lags). Next part is an “i” loop where It is adding empty lines based on value of certain cell. This code lags my macro so bad, like 2-3min when I run it. It even crash. The ironic thing is I have 2 subs branch out and when branch 1 run this code it works fine vs when it enters another branch, it lag/crash. Therefore I know the codes work but I’m confused why one sub works fast and one die. Regardless, I’m looking to improve my codes so it doesn’t lag/crash.
Thank you for your help.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("worksheet1").Select

    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.Insert 
    Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove  
  
    Supply = Range("AO189") 
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numdx As Integer
    numdx = Range("t219") + 4 

    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(Tier + 7).Select 
    For i = 1 To numdx
    Selection.Insert 
    Shift:=xlDown,    
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next i


You likely don't need a loop for this. Instead, use Resize to insert multiple rows in one step.

Your macro is lagging likely due to multiple selections, insertions, and screen updates. Here are a few improvements to optimize the code:
Avoid using .Select and .Selection as much as possible. Directly reference the ranges.
Turn off calculation, events, and updating only once at the beginning and turn them back on at the end.
Minimize the use of loops by inserting multiple rows at once if possible.
Here’s a revised version of your code:
Sub OptimizeMacro()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim numdx As Integer
    Dim Tier As Integer

    ' Turn off updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet1")

    ' Insert one empty line
    ws.Range("F2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' Get the number of rows to insert
    numdx = ws.Range("T219").Value + 4

    ' Insert multiple rows at once
    ws.Rows("F1:F1").Offset(Tier + 7).Resize(numdx).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' Turn updates back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Explanation:
Turning Off Updates: This minimizes the recalculations and screen refreshes while the macro runs.
Direct Range References: Using ws.Range("F2") instead of .Select and .Selection is more efficient and avoids unnecessary screen updates.
Inserting Multiple Rows at Once: Instead of looping to insert rows one at a time, we use Resize(numdx) to insert all rows in one go.
This should help reduce the lag and prevent crashes. Try this optimized code and see if it resolves the performance issues.
